# Caffe's GPU Utilization Is Not Full Enough When Doing Forward Inference, Any Idea?

Tags: python, c++, gpu, caffe, inference

I coded both Python and C++ version of Caffe forward classification scripts to test Caffe's inference performance. The model is trained already. And the results are quite similar, GPU utils is not full enough.

My settings:
 1. Card: Titan XP, 12GB
 2. Model: InceptionV3
 3. Img size: 3*299*299

When batch_size set to 40, GRAM usage can reach 10GB, but the GPU utils can just reach 77%~79%, both for Python and C++. So the performance is about **258 frames/s**.

In my scripts, I loaded the image, preprocess it, load it into the input layer, and then repeat the net_.forward() operation. According to my understanding, this won't cause any Mem copy ops, so ideally should maximally pull up the GPU utils. But I can only reach no more than 80%.

In the [C++ Classification Tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/cpp_classification.html), I found below phrase:

> Use multiple classification threads to ensure the GPU is always fully utilized and not waiting for an I/O blocked CPU thread.

So I tried to use the multi-thread compiled OpenBLAS, and under CPU backend, actually more CPU is involved to do the forwarding, but no use for the GPU backend. Under the GPU backend, the CPU utils will be fixed to about 100%.

Then I even tried to reduce the batch_size to 20, and start two classification processes in two terminals. The result is, GRAM usage increases to 11GB, but the GPU utils decrease to 64%~66%. Finally, the performance decreases to around **200 frames/s**.

Has anyone encountered this problem? I'm really confused.

Any opinion is welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As I had observed, the GPU util is decreased with,

1) low PCI express mode resnet-152(x16)-90% > resnet-152(x8)-80% > resnet-152(x4)-70%
2) large model - VGG-100%(x16) ; ResNet-50(x16)-95~100% ; ResNet-152(x16) - 90%

In addition, if I turn off cuDNN, the GPU Util is always 100%.

So I think there is some problem related with cuDNN, but I don't know more about the problem.

NVCaffe is somewhat better, and MXNet can utilize GPU 100% (resnet-152; x4).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using InceptionV3 with 400+ layers, so the variables amount is huge. I tried this issue on Caffe/TF with/without cuDNN and unfortunately they still hard to get GU above 90%.  For TF experiment in Python, I started to think perhaps because the GIL, the cpu utils is limited, so C++ should be a better way to maximize the GU.

Comment: Another thing about the caffe is that, I looked inside Caffe and found its mem control is loose. So under such a huge scope, GPU perhaps stuck in the mem operations like variables copying, deleting, so that GU is limited. Optimize the Caffe source code on mem control should do this better.